# Cannot start ejabberd server 14.05

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

i have installed ejabberd 14.05 and while installing i had no issues but while starting the server i got the following message:

```
2016-05-24 15:50:37.636 [critical] <0.37.0>@gen_mod:start_module:77 Problem starting the module mod_client_state for host <<"localhost">>
options: []
error: undef
[{mod_client_state,start,[<<"localhost">>,[]],[]},
{gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,69}]},
{lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1336}]},
{ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,66}]},
{application_master,start_it_old,4,
[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}]
2016-05-24 15:50:37.636 [critical] <0.37.0>@gen_mod:start_module:82 ejabberd     initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

I cannot find mod_client_state.erl in src folder.
Sorry I am new to ejabberd and erlang

Comment: can u share your configuration file?

Comment: Hi Kumar, I found the issue. Actually I used ejabberd.yml file of ejabberd 16 where mod_client_state module is present while I was using ejabberd 14.05. its working now. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely a version of ejabberd that does not have `mod_client_state`. mod_client_state feature was added in newer version.

Please upgrade to newer version if you want to use `mod_client_state`.

You need at least version 14.12: https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd-14.12

Comment: Thanks Mickael i was using ejabberd 14.05. Removing mod_client_state definition from module section of ejabberd.yml worked.